# Trouble Accessing Google Spreadsheet Data (Polymer)

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error when trying to access Google-sheets spreadsheet data, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1PiPyN8CK-pP3z8tiz28R7wKkXJxdyyCjaKW0t7SwyT4/od6/public/values?alt=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Thanks,
Flo

Comment: Cross-origin javascript requests are denied by default. That said, you are not allowed to do simple http request by javascript from localhost to google.com unless google.com explicitly allowed it by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am working on a solution for that problem now.

Comment: Hi all, just in case anyone has this problem, this is Actually an OAuth2 issue, if you have a spreadsheet that is private make sure you create a client ID and secret. Also add the URL you will like to access including localhost, in console.developers.google.com under Redirect URIS and Javascript Origins, In the APIs & auth tab, under credentials